Drizzle join results are scrambled
When I execute the following query, results come out scrambled:
    const results = await db.select().from(tweets).where(sql`${tweets.response} is null`)
            .innerJoin(users, eq(users.twitter_id, tweets.authorId))

By scrambled I mean something like this:
{
  tweets: {
    id: 134123442,
    twitter_id: 0,
    created_at: "None",
    authorId: 0,
    is_retweet: false,
    retweetedTweetId: false,
    is_quoted: false,
    quotedTweetId: 2,
    is_reply: false,
    reply_counts: 17
    ...
}

Notice how the field types don't match the key in the dictionary. I'm using sqlite, bun and bun:sqlite. I already ensured that the database is not the one causing the issues.
Any idea as to what could be causing this?

Please update to bun version >=1.1.14.
Check out the changelogs: https://bun.sh/blog/bun-v1.1.14#fixed-bun-sqlite-with-table-joins-crash-fixed

the "bun fixes"? ;)
